# R: Why does summary() random intercept mean and variance differ from manual calculations?

Tags: r, statistics, lme4, variance

If I fit a random intercepts model with R's `lme4::glmer()`, I can extract the resulting vector of intercepts and calculate the mean and the variance of of those intercepts. However, the result from manually calculating these numbers don't seem to match the result of using `summary()` on the model object. What's going on?

Here's the exact working example I'm looking at, showing the disagreement:

```
set.seed(5)
# Load packages
library(fabricatr)
library(lme4)

##############################################################    
# Make some fake data with 10 clusters, 50 observations each
# and the outcomes are correlated in clusters.
##############################################################    

clusters <- rep(1:10, 50)
y <- fabricatr::draw_binary_icc(prob = 0.2, clusters = clusters, ICC = 0.5)

x1 <- rnorm(n = 500)
x2 <- rnorm(n = 500) 
x3 <- rnorm(n = 500)

dat <- data.frame(clusters, y, x1, x2, x3)

##############################################################    
# Fit binary logistic hierarchical regression model with 
# random intercepts, interaction
##############################################################    

m1 <- lme4::glmer(formula = y ~ x1*x2 + x3 + (1|clusters),
              data = dat, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
              nAGQ = 10)

##############################################################    
# Show manual vs. summary() intercept means and variance
##############################################################    

# Variance of random intercepts is 4.28, mean (Intercept) is -1.80
summary(m1)

# But manually the variance is 3.89 and mean is -1.70
intercepts <- coef(m1)$clusters["(Intercept)"]$`(Intercept)`
mean(intercepts)
var(intercepts)
```

Comment: This seems to have more to do with the right understanding of how to calculate the variance of random intercepts, i.e. rather a topic for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: The problem seems to be understanding of parameters in a mixed model. I'd suggest a bit of digging on Google on this topic. Also try checking [GLMMfaq](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) by bolker. Many golden nuggets exist there.